# Capturar Ctrl+Tecla en Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Este es mi escenario:
Un `MainWindow` con un único widget central que es un `QTabWidget`, además de su `QToolBar`. Cada vez que abro un documento nuevo se inserta dentro del `QTabWidget` una instancia de una clase que contiene dos `QTableView` y un `QTextEdit`.
Las `QTableView` tienen un filtro de eventos que hacen que reaccionen de forma especial ante determinadas teclas de función, y eso funciona perfectamente. Sin embargo, cuando pulso teclas como `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+V` o `Ctrl+X` me da un error tipo:

> QAction::eventFilter: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Ctrl+V*

Dentro del `QToolBar` tengo definidas esas acciones (Copiar,Pegar y Cortar), con sus botones y atajos de teclado.

Para el error de `Ambiguous shortcut overload` seteo `shortcutContext` a `WidgetWithChildrenShorCut`, en cada una de estas acciones.

El problema viene que no soy capaz de capturar la combinación de teclas `Ctrl+Tecla`, o al menos no pasa nada cuando lo hago.

Este es un extracto del filtro de eventos:

```
bool Filter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent* event)
{
    qDebug()<<obj->objectName();
    TablaBase* table = qobject_cast<TablaBase*>(obj);
    if( !table )
    {
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);;
    }    
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QModelIndex indice = table->currentIndex();
        QKeyEvent *ke =static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if (ke->matches(QKeySequence::Copy))//primer intento de capturar!!!
        {
            qDebug()<<"Copiando 1";
            return true;
        }       
        switch (ke->key())
        {
        //segundo intento!!!!
        case(Qt::Key_C):// && (ke->modifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier))):
        {
            if (ke->modifiers()==Qt::ControlModifier)
            {
                qDebug()<<"Copiando 2";
                return true;
                break;
            }
        }
        default:
        {
            return false;
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Comment: Eso te está pasando porque hay (al menos) dos `QAction` capturando la misma combinación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la hora de definir *atajos* es importante recordar que cada atajo solo puede ser capturado una única vez.

Se puede limitar facilmente el ámbito de cada `QAction` haciendo uso del método  `setShortcutContext`.

No te puedo facilitar más información al respecto porque ignoro cómo estás cargando los diferentes `QAction`.

Comment: Efectivamente, el problema era que la secuencia Ctrl+C/V/X ya estaba definida en el editor (Cuando puse QTextEdit realmente era una clase derivada de esta en la que había definido esas acciones con sus atajos). Por otro lado, he quitado los shortcut de las QActions en MainWindow. Ahora todo funciona perfectamente